# Angular Animate 1.4 too fast

Tags: angularjs, animation

I have a problem with animation after updating from Angular 1.2 -> 1.4.

I animate page transitions by changing css class on the view container element.
I use ui-router and have ng-class directive on the  element.
The user navigates with arrow keys (event listener in app.run()). This sets the class as a string variable 'navDirection' (left/right) on $rootScope.

After updating it seems that $rootScope.navDirection is set AFTER the animation. So the animation is wrong when user changes direction.

Any suggestions and/or comments is appreciated!

**index.html**

```
<body ng-cloak ng-keydown="handleEvt($event)">
    <div class="page-wrapper page-wrapper--constrain" ng-class="{'page-wrapper--decorate' : decoratePageContent === true}">
        <div class="page-content group position-context">
            <div ui-view class="slide" ng-class="{'at-view-slide-in-left at-view-slide-out-right': navDirection == 'right', 'at-view-slide-in-right at-view-slide-out-left': navDirection == 'left'}"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('my-app', [
    'ui.router',
    'ngAnimate'
]);

// ...

app.run(function ($rootScope, navigationService) {

    $rootScope.handleEvt = function(e) {
        if ($rootScope.navVisible) {
            switch (e.which) {
                // right
                case 37:
                    $rootScope.navDirection = "right";
                    navigationService.navigate(navigationService.getCurrentPageIndex() - 1);
                    break;
                // left
                case 39:
                    $rootScope.navDirection = "left";
                    navigationService.navigate(navigationService.getCurrentPageIndex() + 1);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

// ...
```

Comment: Could you set up a working Codepen of what you have working at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

ngAnimate is refactored internally in version 1.4. It wont run both Javascript and CSS animations parallely. the same effect can achieve now by injecting $animateCSS into javascript defined animations. 
   Moving animations is triggered will always end any pending or active parent class based animations(using ngClass).